# amcl publish frequency map-> odom

Tags: ros, navigation, frequency, rate, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! in my tf tree I have that between /map and /odom there's amcl that publish at 20Hz. How to increase this speed rate?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192010/amcl-publish-frequency-map-%3E-odom/) by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2014-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on  rate of incoming laser messages.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on 2014-09-05**:
ok so where do I have to look? In the robot's urdf where is specified the laserscan? Or somewhere else?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-05**:
its from your laser driver. or you can check your laser message frequency by using `rostopic hz /lasertopicname`

**Comment by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on 2014-09-05**:
ok perfect! I'll check ! thanks!

**Comment by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on 2014-09-07**:
where do I have to modify in order to increase frequency? In the urdf file I have :
<sick_laser_v0 name="laser" parent="base" ros_topic="scan"
update_rate="30" min_angle="-0.97" max_angle="0.97" l_x="0.5" l_y="0.0" l_z="0.25" l_r="0.0" l_p="0.0" l_yaw="0.0"/>

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-07**:
I guess you are using simulator, i have no idead about gazebo. try changing update_rate.  are you getting 30hz for `rostopic hz /lasertopicname`

**Comment by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on 2014-09-07**:
Yes I'm using Gazebo. Still 20 hz after modifying update_rate to 30

**Comment by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on 2014-09-09**:
Other comments?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-09**:
may be you are not modifying right file. try modifying update rate in `gazebo_ros_laser_controller` plugin